# How to profile external class library from console program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, console-application, class-library

I have a console program (c#) which has performance issues. When I started debugging, I saw a while loop which calls a method of a an external class library (out of console solution in c#). I ran performance wizard (with .exe of console program) to check those lines of code (related to class library) which are causing the performance issues. Profiler says the method called in the library is the culprit with high amount of elapsed time. Profiler is unable to drill down further to the lines of code in library to fix the issue.

Can anyone help me in solving the performance issue. I'm using visual studio 2017 professional version.

Comment: I don't have the code but I would like to know the process of performance analyzer  for an external class library.

Comment: Unless is obfuscated, you should be able to decompile it and see what it's doing.

Comment: Even if you could profile it, what are you going to do about it without the code? Unless you want to decompile it and attempt to recompile, but with modern compiler tricks it may be impossible.

Comment: I wanted to check those lines of code which take more time to execute. what do you mean by decompile? how can someone handle these kind of performance issues in a class library? Is it just unit testing?

Comment: You can't fix something in a compiled class library. A decompiler takes a DLL and turns it back into code (maybe).

Comment: As has been mentioned, but not explicitly stated: If the issue is in a third party library then there is nothing you can do. You can decompile it and see what it's doing, but you can't fix the actual library if it's bad code. Though your issue could be in how you implement the library or any other myriad of issues.